# codeigniter 3 validation of associative array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, validation

I am trying to validate an associative array pushed from my JavaScript, using the validation library.

The following code is working except it is only validating (finding the values) for the last array within the associative array, is there a way for it to work for each instance of the array as it runs in the foreach?

code:

```
    if (!empty($JSON)) {
        foreach ($JSON AS $k => $data) {

            foreach ($data AS $key => $value) {
                $this->form_validation->set_data($data);
                if($key == 'itemCode' . $k){
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules($key, 'Item Code', 'required');
                }
                if($key == 'Desc' . $k){
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules($key, 'Description', 'required');
                }
                if($key == 'Qty' . $k){
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules($key, 'Quantity', 'required|numeric');
                }
                if($key == 'Cost' . $k){
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules($key, 'Cost', 'required|numeric');
                }

            }
            //$this->form_validation->reset_validation();

        }
    }
```

array output:

```
[0] => Array(
    [Counter0] => 0
[itemCode0] => 1
[Desc0] => 1
[Qty0] => 1
[Cost0] => 1
[Total0] => 1
)
[1] => Array(
    [Counter1] => 1
[itemCode1] => 2
[Desc1] => 2
[Qty1] => 2
[Cost1] => 2
[Total1] => 4
)
[2] => Array(
    [Counter2] => 2
[itemCode2] => 3
[Desc2] => 3
[Qty2] => 3
[Cost2] => 3
[Total2] => 9
)
[3] => Array(
    [Counter3] => 3
[itemCode3] => 4
[Desc3] => 4
[Qty3] => 4
[Cost3] => 4
[Total3] => 16
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, the set_data function gets called between the set_rules function and according to CI

> You have to call the **set_data()** method before defining any validation rules.

For more information take a look at the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form_validation#validating-an-array-other-than-post)

A possible method would be to catch all data and rules in an array

Below is an example how to achieve that, pls keep in mind i haven't tested it because i wrote it here down but you should be able to see the point

```
$arrValidationData = array();
$arrValidationRules = array();

$arrCatchValidationData = array(
    "itemCode" => array(
        "label" => "Item Code",
        "rules" => "required"
    ),
    "Desc" => array(
        "label" => "Description",
        "rules" => "required"
    ),
    "Qty" => array(
        "label" => "Quantity",
        "rules" => "required|numeric"
    ),
    "Cost" => array(
        "label" => "Cost",
        "rules" => "required|numeric"
    ),
);

if (!empty($JSON)) {
    foreach ($JSON AS $k => $data) {

        foreach ($data AS $key => $value) {

            $keyToCatch = str_replace($k, "", $key);
            if (isset($arrCatchValidationData[$keyToCatch]))
            {
                $arrValidationData[$key] = $value;
                $arrValidationRules[] = array(
                    "field" => $key,
                    "label" => $arrCatchValidationData[$keyToCatch]['label'],
                    "required" => $arrCatchValidationData[$keyToCatch]['rules']
                );
            }
        }
        //$this->form_validation->reset_validation();

    }

    $this->form_validation->set_data($arrValidationData);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($arrValidationRules);

}
```

**update: 30.05.2016**

according to your comment you want to validate post and json data in the same call, in this case you simply have to merge the data

```
$arrValidationData = array_merge($arrValidationData, $_POST);
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the concept, going to try and see if it will work or a variation of it.

Comment: One tiny change (incorrect array value was in the output) and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Worked for the validating of the form, on post however, something is stripping the POST validation data unfortunately so fix one issue, cause another! :(

Comment: not sure what you mean  - this is a solution for your json example - if you need post validation data - you simply have to comment out your set_data function

Comment: I am trying to validate POST data and the JSON array in the same call, if I submit the page the JSON/table data validates perfect but on submit it strips all the POST data before it...